# How To Resolve TF14132: Identity Not Found?

Tags: version-control, tfs, source-control-explorer

I am trying to attach a TFS label to a new file in our collection. The label I am trying to attach already exists, and was created by a different user who left the company a while ago. When I try to view the contents of the existing label, I receive a message that the owner of the label cannot be found - TF14132: Identity not found.

How can I modify this label? 
Is there a way we can update all instances of "Identity not found" to a current/active account?

Answer (score 2):

To update a label created by another user, you'll need the LabelOther permission.  Project Admins have this permission by default - see the [TFS permissions reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx#VersionControl) for details.

Comment: I do have permission, but I can't change the the label due to the identity not found error. When I click "Edit Label", I get a popup from Visual Studio saying "The label 'xyz' could not be loaded. TF14045: The identity TF14132: Idenity not found. is not a recognized identity" - Makes me think there's an error inside another error now!

Comment: Are you able to create a new label without hitting any errors?  Are you seeing any other instances of TF14132 for this user?  For example, there have been some instances of users seeing this in the history view.